# Why does Angular 2's *ngFor generated HTML slowdown event processing in IE on Win 10?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, angular

I've been writing some code that creates a fake selection rectangle based on mouseDown/mouseMove/mouseUp events.  The rectangle is updated as you move your mouse, and this movement is smooth in Chrome, but is painfully slow in Internet Explorer and Edge (using the most recent versions on an up-to-date Windows 10).

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I can't work out why this should be so.  I've been reducing my code to the essentials to track down what's causing the issue, and I'm stuck after having determined that this static code works smoothly in IE:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Fast</td><td>Fast</td><td>Fast</td><td>Fast</td><td>Fast</td>
</tr>
```

... whereas that same functionality over these TDs generated by Angular 2 have significantly poorer performance in Internet Explorer and Edge:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <th>Name</th>
    <td *ngFor="let col of cols">Slow</td>
</tr>
```

I've spent some time creating a plnkr that includes an easy toggle between the two versions that helps show the problem when using the affected browsers:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/782sd5CbM4psy98Wr1tj?p=preview

I would love it if somebody who actually knows what they're doing could help shed some light on this.  (It's worth pointing out that reducing the number of <td> elements generated by Angular reduces the performance impact in the affected browsers, but due to the nature of the real project reducing the amount of cells visible is unfortunately not an option.)

*Note*:  I have since managed to try this on a Windows 7 system using the most recent version of IE11.  This system is noticably slower than the laptop I'd tried this on previously, yet /doesn't/ suffer from this issue.  I'm genuinely gabberflasted.

Comment: Have you tried with `prodMode` enabled? `devMode` is known to cause performance issues in IE.

Comment: Hi Günter - yes, I've tried that.  It /may/ make a difference to the rate at which the <td>'s are generated (I haven't measured) but it doesn't affect the mousemove events as in my demo, which continue to perform poorly.

Comment: You could try some throttle feature so not every event updates the DOM. This should be quite easy using observables

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but throttling would achieve the exact opposite:  the selection would stutter even more, rather than be respond more smoothly.  Something about how Angular generates the table cells is throttling those events too much in IE (since the 1st example works fine, but the 2nd is jittery).  It's harder to explain than it is to see - hence the demo:  open up the plnkr in IE and toggle between the two variations using the checkbox.

Comment: These might be interesting https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8112, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7088

Comment: Thanks Günter - I looked a both those issues on github.  Unfortunately, while there seems some to be some overlap, those issues deal with the speed at which *ngFor generates the HTML, whereas my issue is with a (what I find a baffling) performance hit with events such as mousemove after the HTML has already been generated.

Comment: Might be worth a bug report with your Plunker for the Angular team to investigate.

Comment: Gunter, I've recently updated this question with new information (specifically, how the problem occurs on Windows 10, but not on Windows 7).  Does that perhaps help you to narrow down the problem?  Because nobody else seems to know what's going on, and I'm drawing a blank as well.

Comment: Did you resolve this ?